# C#: How to add static rows/data to DataGridView?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I want to preview content in the datagridview inside Design view using visual studio 2010. I know how to program in some data but I'm wondering if I can add the data manually so that I can preview it without building.

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot view the actual data in the design view...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible through the designer (see **[here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/bc6c84c1-0a3a-4c97-8966-30be371576d9)**).  The best you can do is see what columns are present in your data source, but even adding a data source from the DataSources tab will not populate the grid.

Answer (score 0):

You can derive a form/usercontrol from the one in question and you will see the results of changing the base class in the derived class's designer.